# iis asp.net track constant traffic

Tags: iis, monitor, network-traffic

I have a Windows Server 2022 running iis with 1 classic ASP.Net and one .Net Core / Blazor application.

Using the Microsoft application "AppNetworkCounter", I noticed that there is constant inbound and outbound traffic from w3wp.exe (the iis host process). What bothers me is that there is a constant minimum traffic of 40kb/s up and 60kb/s down. **This traffic does not change even when I turn off both applications running in iis**. When I open a page in one of the iis sites, the traffic shortly spikes and then returns to the constant up/download from before.

So I am looking for a way to find out what is causing this traffic and what the destination/source is (AppNetworkCounter doesn't show this).

I have tried "Microsoft Network Monitor", but to no success due to the complexity of the software and the many sessions being open through the applications running.

Is there an easy/easier way to find out what's going on?

Comment: How did you connect to this server? RDP connections also generate traffic on the wire, and there can be many more possibilities. No success with Network Monitor indicates that you need to put more efforts there, not otherwise. Overall, this is not programming related and you might ask your network administrators for further guidance.

Comment: I am the network administrator and RP does not generate traffic over w3wp.exe. 
I am specifically talking about this process, not server traffic in general...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using the application "Microsoft Message Analyzer". It's possible to filter by IIS traffic. This helped me track down the culprit and clear it (a known application running on the server).

Answer (score 1):

You may consider installing Wireshark on your server. Wireshark can capture and analyze traffic patterns in your network. This is useful for understanding user behavior, optimizing service delivery, identifying abnormal traffic, etc. Use this tool to capture and filter traffic to focus on the w3wp.exe process, and then analyze the captured packets to identify the source/destination of ongoing traffic.